# Completely change the design of a page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

Is there a way I can fully customize a page in Drupal? I don't want the Drupal header or any other HTML generated by Drupal to show up, but I want to be able to access the Drupal functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an alernative `page.tpl.php` file. Eg. `page--front.tpl.php`

Not sure it's the best way to do this but it will work. You can strip anything you don't want out of the file so it is totally different to other pages.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want a new page template (as opposed to a node template). This does not quite work out of the box in Drupal 7 so there are a few steps:

**Step 1** 
Create a new content type for this specially themed page, call it "special" or whatever...

**Step 2**
Add this code to your theem's template.php file.  (Replace "yourthemename" in the code below with your theme's machine name, that is to say the name of your theme folder in /sites/all/)

```
 function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
      }
     }
```

**Step 3**
Create a new page template in your theme folder and name it after the new content type.  so for example: `page--special.tpl.php` and "special" being the name of the content type.  Customize away!

**Step 4**
Clear cache

**Step 5**
Create a new peice of content using your new content type -- it will be in the design of your new page template.

The end result will be like having a completely separate theme but staying within your existing theme.

Note, I wrote a blog post on how to do this for Drupal 6 but if you read down the comments, there are ideas and links how do this for D7 but basically what I have said here.

http://highrockmedia.com/blog/creating-custom-content-type-page-templates-drupal-php

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is pretty flexible:

```
<?php
$json = array(
  'body' => 'This is the body of the page.',
  'title' => 'This is the page title',
);
return drupal_json_output($json);
?>
```

Comment: He's looking for a completely different layout, no header etc... Can you explain how your code would do that?